# Image upload and Image manipulation in Codeigniter is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, codeigniter

Everybody

I am facing problem with image displaying,manipulation and thumbnail creation.My image upload is ok and it's stored in uploads folder then thumbs folder.Now i want to display these images together in a view page.Here,is my code.Please,please help me.I am waiting.Thanks in advance.

Here is my Controller(gallery)

```
<?php
class gallery extends CI_Controller 
{

function gallery()
{

parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('Gallery_Model');

}

  function index()
  {

if ($this->input->post('upload')){

 $this->Gallery_Model->do_upload();

}

$data['images'] =  $this->Gallery_Model->get_images();

  $this->load->view('gallery_view',$data);

   }

}
```

Here is my Model(gallery_model)

```
<?php

class Gallery_Model extends CI_Model

{

var $gallery_path;

var $gallery_path_2;

function Gallery_Model()

{

  parent::__construct();

  $this->gallery_path=realpath(APPPATH . '../uploads');

  $this->gallery_path_2=base_url() .'uploads';

}

function do_upload()
 {

  $config = array(

  'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',

  'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path

  );

  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  $this->upload->do_upload();

  $image_data = $this->upload->data();


  $config = array(

  'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],

  'new_image' => $this->gallery_path .'/thumbs',

  'maintain_ration' =>true,

  'width' =>150,

  'height' =>100

  );

  $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

  $this->image_lib->resize();

}

function get_images()
{

  $files=  scandir($this->gallery_path);

    $files=  array_diff($files, array(',',',','thumbs'));

$images = array();

foreach ($files as $file)

{

  $images[]=array(

  'url' =>$this->gallery_path_2 . $file,

  'thumb_url' =>$this->gallery_path_2 .'thumbs/'. $file,

  );

}
return $images;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view, try something like this:

```
<?php foreach($images as $image){?>
<img src="<?php echo $images['url'];?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

And do something similar for your thumbnails. I don't know what your view looks like so I can't give you any sort of specifics.